# Older movie like They Live

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a movie back in the 70's that had almost the exact plot as the movie [*They Live*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096256/?ref_=nv_sr_1). The main character was hunting alien impersonators with a device that made them look like a thermographic image when you looked at them through it.

At the end of the movie when he is near death, he sees that the woman he was running with turns out to be one of these said aliens. Don't remember the name of it. Just remember the plot was very much like *They Live* movie.

Comment: Hi there! :) that's a start! Maybe you could take a look at [this guide on asking story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories? Like, did you watch it in English, at a drive-in maybe? Any info is good to add!

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/211436/60s-70s-sci-fi-film-where-two-competing-alien-races-send-agents-disguised-as-hum (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 7):

"The Love War" (1970 TV movie)?

Here is the plot from Wikipedia:

> Two warring planets choose to settle their conflict over which of them
>   will take over the planet Earth, each sending a trio of soldiers to
>   Earth to fight to the death. The combatants, disguised as human
>   beings, can only identify each other by using special visors.
>
> Kyle, one of the combatants, falls in love with Sandy, a woman he
>   meets during his stay in a small town. In the end, despite cheating by
>   the other side, Kyle is the sole survivor. But before he can signal
>   his people he has won, Sandy shoots him with one of the alien weapons.
>   A dying Kyle then learns that Sandy is also an alien; the other side
>   has cheated twice. She chose duty to her people over her love for him.
>   Weeping as she watches him die, she asks him what their half-breed
>   children would have been. The film’s closing shot shows Sandy through
>   the visor as she really is: a hideously scarred humanoid. The Earth
>   faces an orgy of destruction and the extermination of humanity.

You can watch the entire movie on YouTube in 5 different parts, with each part running about 15 minutes long. Below is part 2, and you can see the character played by Angie Dickinson looking through the visor and discovering the man she loves is an alien. This happens at 9:18 of the video.